# Showing cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is $\Bbb R_{+}$ under multiplication cyclic? Would it suffice to show that this group is isomorphic to a cyclic group? For example, $\Bbb Z_+$ is cyclic under addition, $\Bbb R_{+}$ is isomorphic to it, then $\Bbb R_{+}$ is cyclic too?

Thanks!

Comment: $\Bbb Z_+$ is not even a group under addition, it is only a semigroup.

Comment: @Travis The most likely $\mathbb Z_+$ stands for $(\mathbb Z,+)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not cyclic; this would imply the reals were countable. If you haven't seen cardinality, you can argue explicitly as follows: if $x$ were a generator, then we can assume $x > 1$ (else take $1/x$ for the generator). But nothing between $x$ and $x^2$ can be in the group generated by $x$.

Comment: I have another question too. Would showing that a group is isomorphic to a cyclic group suffice to conclude that the group is cyclic? Can you please comment on this too?

Comment: As for your other question, the property of being cyclic (like any property you can describe using the first-order language of group theory) is invariant under isomorphism [so in other words, yes!]. The reason is that an isomorphism would have to take a generator to a generator (which you should check). You should think of isomorphic groups as being "the same," so properties that describe groups (like "cyclic" or "abelian") shouldn't change if you take two groups that are isomorphic.